# Reset auto increment and reset ids of remaning rows

Tags: php, sql, database, database-design

Currently i run a script which will delete every row with a timestamp older than 30 days

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE `timestamp` NOT BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Everything works great but i'd like to clean up the remaning tables.

Sample problem

I have a table with 300 rows, i delete the first 295 rows i am now left with 5 rows with the ids 296, 297, 298, 299 and 300.

I'd like to reset auto increment to 1 and update the current rows so they are 296->1, 297->2, 298->3, 299->4, 300->5.

Is there anything built in to do this ?

Currently i use this SQL to fix the starting point of the auto increment `ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

The SQL is great but wont start from 1 if there is already id's above 1, in this example 296, 297, 298, 299 and 300 then the next row will start from 301.

What area my options is there anything built in to change 296->1, 297->2, 298->3, 299->4, 300->5 ? or what are the possibilities, i havent ben able to find anything on the subject.

Comment: Don't do it, just leave the values as they are. You shouldn't care what the values are, only that they're unique.

Comment: Stability is one the measures of a good primary key. What happens if a user or app memorized id 300 and makes changes to the db assuming that value still references the same thing?